# Aerospike nodes without sync

Tags: caching, aerospike

We want to deploy aerospike as replacement for memcache. We have two servers to deploy it.

For cache we don't want data replication across multiple nodes. In our architecture we have one cache on each node.

Now issue with aerospike is it's shared nothing architecture which increases the sync between two nodes. Data transfer leads to lot of bandwidth between two machines. As we are on 1gbps network and caching space is around 4Gb, it really uses up all bandwidth once the cache start to filling up.

We just want to use aerospike without its cluster support.

Anyway to turn it off in the aerospike.conf ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's definitely possible. In the namespace configuration you would state that the replication-factor is 1:

```
namespace cache {
    memory-size 4G
    storage-engine memory
    replication-factor 1
    high-water-memory-pct 80 # Evict non-zero TTL data if capacity exceeds 80%
    default-ttl 432000 # select a non-zero TTL that makes sense to your use-case
}
```

With a non-zero TTL the eviction of data happens based on a histogram, with the result being similar to the Memcached LRU eviction. What that number of seconds is will be something you need to estimate. Just be aware that TTL is reset whenever data is written to the record.

Comment: Just be aware that the client handles writes efficiently, and only talks to the cluster node which is the master of the record's partition. If you have replication configured the write will be synced to the node which owns the replica partition, then the client is notified of a successful write. The overhead is probably less than you expect, and makes for a more durable cluster. Though if you're purely going for a cache, and are fine with it being volatile, then no problem.

Comment: Thanks for quick revert. I implemented the same, but still seeing bandwidth spike in newrelic. By using asmonitor i think syncing is stopped, but data still read on the private ip. Can we not put it on the 127.0.0.1 to avoid any network interface issues.In client we are putting 127.0.0.1 to read the data from aerospike.

Comment: When you change the namespace configuration you have to restart. With regards to the configuration specifics, please post a question on the discussion forums http://discuss.aerospike.com . There are devOps, server, and client engineers assigned to all the topics and you'll get a quick response.

Comment: thanks for the input. I read somewhere binding to localhost is not possible on aerospike. Thanks for your time and input.